# Can Ruby math operators be stored in a hash and applied dynamically later?

Tags: ruby, operators

Is there any way to set a hash with values such as `<`, `>`, `%`, `+`, etc? 
I want to create a method that accepts an array of ints, and a hash with parameters.

In the method below `array` is the array to be filtered, and `hash` is the parameters. The idea is that any number less than `min` or more than `max` is removed.

```
def range_filter(array, hash) 
  checker={min=> <, ,max => >} # this is NOT  working code, this the line I am curious about
  checker.each_key {|key| array.delete_if {|x| x checker[key] args[key] }
  array.each{|num| puts num}
end
```

The desired results would be

```
array=[1, 25, 15, 7, 50]
filter={min=> 10, max=> 30} 
range_filter(array, filter)
# => 25
# => 15
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I dynamically call a math operator in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060239/can-i-dynamically-call-a-math-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby, even math is a method invocation.  And math symbols can be stored as ruby symbols.  These lines are identical:

```
1 + 2         # 3
1.+(2)        # 3
1.send(:+, 2) # 3
```

So armed with that, storing it as a hash is simple:

```
op = { :method => :> }
puts 1.send(op[:method], 2) # false
puts 3.send(op[:method], 2) # true
```

Comment: `!=` is a special syntax case.  It actually executes the `==` method, and then flips the resulting boolean.  So you can't run `!=` as a method directly sadly. You have to do `!1.send(:==, 2)`.  You may have to detect that symbol and special case it if you want to support this.

Comment: Sadly, I'm on 1.8.7 still.  But I'm glad to hear they fixed that inconsistency then :)

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, `!` is also a method, so it would be more like `1.send(:==, 2).send(:!)`.

Answer (score 5):

sure, store them as strings (or symbols) and use `object.send(function_name, argument)`

```
> operators = ["<", ">", "%", "+"]
=> ["<", ">", "%", "+"] 
> operators.each{|op| puts ["   10 #{op} 3: ", 10.send(op,3)].join}
   10 < 3: false
   10 > 3: true
   10 % 3: 1
   10 + 3: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work just like expected:

```
def range_filter(array, args)
  checker = { :min=> :<, :max => :> }
  checker.each_key { |key| array.delete_if {|x| x.send checker[key], args[key] } }
  array.each { |num| puts num }
end
```

Just use `Symbol`s instead of the plain operators. The operators are special methods of number objects so you can just use `send` and their `Symbol` equivalent to call them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Guess using symbols doesn't add readability in this case. Try this:

```
checkers = 
  [ lambda{ |x| x > 10 },
    lambda{ |x| x < 30 } ]

[1, 25, 15, 7, 50].select{ |x| checkers.all?{ |c| c[x] } } 
#=> [25, 15]
```

**Update**

Compare with (it works too, but what if you wanted `lambda{ |x| x % 3 == 1 }` ?)

```
checkers = 
  { :> => 10,
    :< => 30 }

[1, 25, 15, 7, 50].select{ |x| checkers.all?{ |k, v| x.send(k, v) } } 
#=> [25, 15]
```