# Can I dynamically call a math operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

Is there something like this in ruby?

```
send(+, 1, 2)
```

I want to make this piece of code seem less redundant

```
if op == "+"
  return arg1 + arg2
elsif op == "-"
  return arg1 - arg2
elsif op == "*"
  return arg1 * arg2
elsif op == "/"
  return arg1 / arg2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yup, simply use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) (or, better yet, [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send)) like so:

```
arg1.public_send(op, arg2)
```

This works because most operators in Ruby (including `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, [and more](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4)) simply call methods. So `1 + 2` is the same as `1.+(2)`.

You may also want to whitelist `op` if it’s user input, e.g. `%w[+ - * /].include?(op)`, as otherwise the user will be able to call arbitrary methods (which is a potential security vulnerability).

Comment: What is that `%w` notation? Or is it just cleaner than `["+", "-", ... ].include?(op)`

Comment: `%w[a b c]` is equivalent to `['a', 'b', 'c']` - it's just a shorthand for an array of strings (elements separated by whitespace).

Comment: is there are solution that would allow for += operators to work as well?

Comment: @burningpony You can’t `send` operators, only methods, so no. But there’s no reason not just do an explicit assignment using the return value of `send`.

Answer (score 1):

As an other option, if your operator and operands happen to be in string format, say from a `gets` method, you can also use `eval`:

For example:

`a = '1'; b = '2'; o = '+'`

`eval a+o+b`

becomes

`eval '1+2'`

which returns `3`