# How do I convert a math operator character to perform its operation?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do something like this. It is giving me an error, which I guess is because `op` is a string. Is it possible to convert a string of a math operator to be an operator?

```
def calc(op)
  a = 9
  b = 5
  a op b
end

p calc('-')
p calc('+')
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting display of the code!

Comment: I concur with @Arup's answer, but would like to point out that you could replace his line `a.send(op,b)` with `eval "#{a} #{op} #{b}"`.  If `op = '+'`, this becomes `eval "9 + 5"`, which would be `14`.  Some advise that `eval` always be avoided, because it can be dangerous if a user has supplied the string that is sent to `eval`, but here I think it has pretty much the same effect as `a.send(op,b)`.  Again, I'd use `send`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I dynamically call a math operator in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060239/can-i-dynamically-call-a-math-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 12):

Here it is using [`Object#send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
def calc(op)
  a = 9
  b = 5
  a.send(op,b)
end

p calc('-')
p calc('+')
# >> 4
# >> 14
```